# how to update contextMenu using Jquery contextMenu X2

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

i have added this contextMenu like this:

```
buildContentMenu = {

   commands : {}, // i'm add items from external function

   makeMenu: function makeMenu(){

     $.contextMenu({ 
        selector: '.fullRegularRow',
        items: this.commands,
        events: {
            show : function(options){
                 var serverId = this.attr("id").replace("server","").replace(/\-+/g, '.');
                 var fanMode = this.attr("fanMode");
                 var powerMode = this.attr("powerMode");
                 menuListManager.addOptionsToMenu(serverId, fanMode, powerMode)
                 console.log(serverId);

            }
        }        
    });
```

Now i want to add itmes to the menu list.

so i update the commands object and try to update the contectMenu like this but not work for me:

```
    $.contextMenu('update');
```

Any body can help me how to update my menu?

Answer (score 1):

After few hours, i found the answer.

The point is that if i want to build the Menu before it shown, i have tu use **build**.
Now, before the menu is ready to show, i can to rearange what i want to show by edit the Object Commands (in my case).

this is my finel code:

```
        $.contextMenu({ 
        selector: '.fullRegularRow, .COLservers4, .COLservers2, .quarterOf2U, .fullDoubledRow, .fullQuadrdRow',
            build : function($triggerElement, e){
                var fanmode = ( $triggerElement[0].attributes["data-fanmode"].value);
                var powermode = ( $triggerElement[0].attributes["data-powermode"].value);

                if(fanmode == "STANDARD_MODE"){
                    menuListManager.commands["strdFanMode"] = {callback: function(key, opt){ menuList.sendMenuRequest(key, serverURL); }, name: "Fan mode", icon: "fas fa-check"};
                    menuListManager.commands["zutaFanMode"] = {callback: function(key, opt){ menuList.sendMenuRequest(key, serverURL); }, name: "Fan mode"};
                }else{
                    menuListManager.commands["strdFanMode"] = {callback: function(key, opt){ menuList.sendMenuRequest(key, serverURL); }, name: "Fan mode"};
                    menuListManager.commands["zutaFanMode"] = {callback: function(key, opt){ menuList.sendMenuRequest(key, serverURL); }, name: "Fan mode", icon: "fas fa-check"}; 
                }

                if(powermode == "STANDARD_MODE"){
                    menuListManager.commands["strdPowerMode"] = {callback: function(key, opt){ menuList.sendMenuRequest(key, serverURL); }, name: "Power mode", icon: "fas fa-check"};
                    menuListManager.commands["zutaPowerMode"] = {callback: function(key, opt){ menuList.sendMenuRequest(key, serverURL); }, name: "Power mode"};
                }else{
                    menuListManager.commands["strdPowerMode"] = {callback: function(key, opt){ menuList.sendMenuRequest(key, serverURL); }, name: "Power mode"};
                    menuListManager.commands["zutaPowerMode"] = {callback: function(key, opt){ menuList.sendMenuRequest(key, serverURL); }, name: "Power mode", icon: "fas fa-check"}; 
                }

                return {
                    callback: function(){},
                    items: menuListManager.commands,      
                };

            }
    });
```

hope it will help to someone.